# Product Attribute swatch image in template

Tags: magento2, product, product-attribute, template

I have a product Attribute that can be set as a swatch with an image.

[image]

How can I get the swatch image src in my template ?

I can use the following to get the label.

`$attribute_value = $_product->getData( $attributeCode );
 $optionText = $attr->getSource()->getOptionText( $attribute_value );`

Thanks.